# Worded Differential Equation Question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A kite is rising at a rate proportional to its height at any time, $\frac{dh}{dt} = kh, 0<h<300$ where h is in meters and t in minutes, k constant. The initial height is 2 metres and after 1 minute it climbs to 20 metres. Prove using calculus methods that the height, h at any time works out to be $h= 2e^{2.303t}$.

Comment: What is your attempt?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE. As stated in the comments, we like to see your work before answering questions. This is *not* a place for you to dump your homework questions (buy a Chegg membership if that's really what you want...).

Nevertheless, I'll help since it's your first question.

$$\frac{dh}{dt} = kh \implies \int \frac{dh}{h} = k\int dt$$
$$\ln|h| = kt + C \space\space \text{ for some } C \in \mathbb{R}$$
$$h(t) = Ae^{kt} $$
$$h(0) = A = 2 \text{ meters} $$
$$h(1) = 2e^k = 20 \text { meters} \implies k = \ln(10) $$
$$h(t) = 2e^{\ln(10)t} \approx 2e^{2.303t} $$

This method is called *separation of variables* for a first order ODE with initial values. I suggest you read up on this.